# Codeception - Run acceptance tests in multiple environments

Tags: php, codeception

I'm trying to run tests for multiple sites by using different environments. The sites all follow the same template, so a generic test is enough to cover them all.

In my acceptance.suite.yml file I set up all the environments with the different urls.

In my Cest file, I have a load of functions that are called in a specific environment, and set up some variables that may differ between sites, log in info, etc.

I then call the same function for every environment.

When I'm running the acceptance tests I tell it which environments to run using multiple '--env foo'.

This all works, but I have over 20 sites to test, which means writing 20 '--env foo' every time I want to run a test. Seems a bit much.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed codeception using composer, you can edit the following file:

vendor/codeception/codeception/src/Codeception/Codecept.php

Navigate to the run function (Around line 125), and change the following:

```
    if (!$selectedEnvironments or empty($environments)) {
        $this->runSuite($settings, $suite, $test);
        return;
    }

    foreach ($environments as $env => $config) {
        if (!in_array($env, $selectedEnvironments)) {
            continue;
      }
```

Into:

```
    if (/*!$selectedEnvironments or*/empty($environments)) {
        $this->runSuite($settings, $suite, $test);
        return;
    }

    foreach ($environments as $env => $config) {
        /*if (!in_array($env, $selectedEnvironments)) {
            continue;
        }*/
```

Now it should run all environments by running "codecept run". You can modify the function as per your requirements, to for example only use a specific environment if specified, or else run all environments.

Actually if you change the last bit to the following, it will use the specified environments if set using --env, and else execute all:

```
 foreach ($environments as $env => $config) {
        if ($selectedEnvironments) {
            if (!in_array($env, $selectedEnvironments)) {
                continue;
            }
        }
```

If anybody knows how to cleanly rewrite a core function in Codecept.php without editing the file directly, I would love to hear because that would of course be a cleaner solution :)